# Random motion of molecules

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, kinematics, molecules, gas

If we are given the initial position and the velocity of an object (ex. a ball) according to an inertial frame of reference we can calculate its position and velocity for another given time with high precision relative to the precision of a single molecules motion. Why is this not the case for a single gas molecule? Why can't we describe the motion of a single gas  molecule as accurately as we describe the motion of a ball?

To be clear, I am not asking why nature is the way it is, rather i am asking what is the physical difference between a ball and a molecule which causes the lack of determinism between the motion of the two?

Comment: Are you talking about a molecule in the atmosphere or a single molecule in a vacuum?

Comment: @Ziggurat I am talking about a molecule in a vacuum.

Comment: In statistical mechanics there is no assumption that the molecule is not moving along a straight line when not interacting with other molecules or the walls. When it interacts though, statmech assumes it will change direction in a random way since there can be a lot of unknown parameters (where the other particle is, how it is moving, spinning or shaped). That makes the problem _deliberately_ probabilistic.

Comment: -1. Unlcear. When you say *random motion* do you mean Brownian Motion? Or are you asking about the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle? If you are asking about a single isolated molecule, without any collisions, why do you think its motion is *random*?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why we can't find the motion of a single gas particle in a vacuum with some reasonable precision in a classical sense. It will simply go in a straight line at uniform velocity. At such scales and more evidently at smaller scales quantum mechanics and the uncertainty principle come into play. We can solve for the time evolution of the particle's trajectory just like we can for classical mechanics but in this case we have an evolving probability distribution which in the classical limit (treat the atom as a ball) leads to the same results as a ball. The problem is not very interesting.

But the reason why we don't solve for motions of atoms in general is usually because there are huge numbers of them, solving 10^23 equations of motion is not easy/reasonable  to do which is why we use statistical mechanics in that case.

Comment: But what would be the direction of it's velocity.

Comment: The direction of its velocity would be the direction the particle is moving in.  I think it's one of those concepts that's good to not overthink.